# Application crashes when run on other devices

Tags: android

I'm having a problem with Android Studio and testing my application. I'm testing it on two identical One Plus One devices. It works fine on the one I've been using since the start, but today I tested it on the second device and it crashes when it gets to a certain part of the app.

The app in question connects two or more devices using Google Play services real time multiplayer. One the first device, it's searching for peers to play with. The second device was to test that they can connect.

However, when the button is clicked to search for devices, it crashes the app.
I will print the logs below, but I'm wondering is there some other reason why this happens? Why it works on the device I've used from the start, but doesn't on the exact same device?

Any help is GREATLY appreciated. It's really hindering my progress and Google hasn't returned much in the line of helpful results.

Logs:

```
03-30 17:21:49.330 10436-10436/com.example.anna.pokerapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.example.anna.pokerapp, PID: 10436
                                                                         Theme: themes:{default=overlay:system, iconPack:system, fontPkg:system, com.android.systemui=overlay:system, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:system}
                                                                         java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21158)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204) 
                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21158) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient must be connected.
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.games.Games.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.games.Games.zzi(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.api.RealTimeMultiplayerImpl.getSelectOpponentsIntent(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.example.anna.pokerapp.QuickGame.onStartMatchClicked(QuickGame.java:50)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204) 
                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21158) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: You need to run googleapiclient.connect() when your app loads in order to use their services

Comment: 'googleapiclient.connect()' is implemented and running. It works on device 1 but not on device 2. Any idea why this is?

Comment: You need to sign into a Google account on the other phone, perhaps? And is your code not checking the Google client status with `mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()` before trying to use it?

Comment: If you search with the `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient must be connected.` error from the error log, you'll find lots of previous questions and answers. This could/should perhaps be marked as a duplicate of one of those.

Comment: It is signed into a Google account on that device, and checks the status of the connection beforehand. The other questions I've found haven't been like the problem here due to, as stated before, it working perfectly fine on one device, and just crashing on the other and spitting out this in logcat. It's using a different Google account on the second device - could it be to do with that?

Comment: Well, is anything in your code referencing a specific Google account? If not, then any Google account should be fine of course. And of course you could add the code section that crashes to your question and someone might get some bright idea from that.